# Remover ultimo caractere de uma string, quando o caractere for um espaço em branco

Tags: java, string

Boa tarde.

Estou programando em java e quero pegar as inicias de um nome, no caso:

"Jonas Barros Santos"

Tem que aparecer : **JS**

O código que uso, faz isso, porém se a pessoa colocar o nome com espaço no final, meu código não funciona, dando uma exception.

"Jonas Barros Santos "

Queria uma ajuda para resolver esse problema.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String nome = "Jonas Barros Santos ";
        String nomeAbrev = null;
        int posicaoUltimoEspaco = nome.lastIndexOf(" ");
        String primeiraLetraUltimoNome = "";
        if (posicaoUltimoEspaco > 0) {
            primeiraLetraUltimoNome = nome.substring(posicaoUltimoEspaco + 1, posicaoUltimoEspaco + 2);
        }
        String primeiraLetra = nome.substring(0, 1);
        nomeAbrev = primeiraLetra + primeiraLetraUltimoNome;
        System.out.println(nomeAbrev);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa a função trim(), por exemplo, nome.trim() tira o espaço de inicio e final. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm

Comment: funcionou como eu precisava. Grata

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar método o trim() que tira espaço apenas do início e fim da string.

Answer (score 0):

É simples Amanda, como o @Marconi comentou, aplicando um `trim` na parte da direita da tua `string`, é eliminado o espaço em branco independente de quantos tiver, logo tu pode utilizar o teu código que não irá acusar error por acessar um índice inexistente na `string`. Fica assim:

```
String nome = "Jonas Barros Santos     ";
String nomeAbrev = "";
nomeAbrev = nome.replaceAll("\\s+$","");
int posicaoUltimoEspaco = nomeAbrev.lastIndexOf(" ");
String primeiraLetraUltimoNome = "";
if (posicaoUltimoEspaco > 0) {
      primeiraLetraUltimoNome = nomeAbrev.substring(posicaoUltimoEspaco + 1, posicaoUltimoEspaco + 2);
}
String primeiraLetra = nomeAbrev.substring(0, 1);
nomeAbrev = primeiraLetra + primeiraLetraUltimoNome;
System.out.println(nomeAbrev);
```