# Como excluir espaços em branco

Tags: java

**Exemplo**

```
String str = "  texto com     espaços   em     branco           ";
```

**Resultado**
    "texto com espaços em branco"

Comment: nas extremidades com `String#trim()`, já tem uma [pergunta recente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203366/28595) sobre ele.

Comment: Não é so nas extremidades, mas tambem os espaços demais.

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar uma expressão regular:

```
System.out.println("  texto com   espaços   em  branco".replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

Resultado

> texto com espaços em branco

Para remover também os espaços nas extremidades, pode aplicar primeiro a função trim():

```
System.out.println("  texto com   espaços em  branco".trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

A ideia é que a expressão regular `\s` corresponde a qualquer caractere de espaço em branco.

Caso um padrão qualquer estiver seguido de um +, significa que esse padrão precisa aparecer 1 ou mais vezes. Neste caso, \s+, casa (faz match) com um ou mais espaços em branco consecutivos.

Esta informação é depois passada à função ReplaceAll que substitui os espaços consecutivos encontrados, por apenas um espaço em branco.

Fica aqui o [exemplo](https://ideone.com/qbgPVz) e a [fonte](http://programming.guide/java/removing-duplicate-whitespace.html).

Comment: Já ia comentar isso, tava ficando espaço pra tras nas extremidades.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar a classe Scanner

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(text);
    String t = null;
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        if(t == null)
            t = s.next();
        else
            t = t +" "+s.next();
    }       
    System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.

Comment: Scanner é uma classe de Java,                                  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Não adicione explicações nos comentários. Entre em [edit] e complemente sua resposta original. E não só faça a referência à documentação, explique o que seu código faz com palavras. O que pode ser trivial, para outros usuários pode não ser.